# Permission denied error while converting mp3 to wav using pydub

Tags: python, pydub

I am trying to convert many MP3 files in a folder to WAV using AudioSegment but I am getting permission denied error. Here is the code I'm using:

```
from os import path
from pydub import AudioSegment
# files                                                                         
src = open('C:/Users/user_name/Documents/Test/dataset/audio/folder_name')
for file in src:
    new_file=file +".wav"
    # convert wav to mp3                                                            
    sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(file)
    sound.export(new_file, format="wav")
```

Here is the error I got:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Please can anyone tell me a better way to do this

Comment: don't you need to add back the path to the export file name? or any other valid path?

Comment: `open()` isn't something you can do with a *folder*, that's for reading data from files.  `os.listdir()` is how you get the filenames contained in a folder.